# Facebook request dialog inside app

Tags: facebook, dialog, request

I'm trying to popup a request dialog (of the list of friends) inside the canvas app, but I'm having troubles and I'm not finding any help on tutorials.

Here the code after the authentication, etc.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '[**myid**]',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
<button id="send-to-many">Send to Many</button>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById('send-to-many').onclick = function() {
 FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'You should learn more about blabla].',
  }, Log.info.bind('send-to-many callback'));
}
</script>
```

any ideas or any examples of how to initiate the JS on a FB canvas?

Comment: What problem are you having? Are there any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Log is not defined

Comment: do you know any good example of how can integrate a friend request popup-link?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second parameter in the FB.ui() function is supposed to be a callback function.  Try removing it and either replace it with null or a function that is defined or with an inline function. If you do need to call Log.info.bind, make sure the function is defined and the defining script gets included. For now, try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('send-to-many').onclick = function() {
 FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'You should learn more about blabla].',
  }, function(response) {
     //Log.info.bind('send-to-many callback'));
  alert('callback called');
  })
}
</script>
```

Facebook documentation has examples and code for what you are trying to do. Check their [requests documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `Log.info.bind` , change it to `console.log()`

```
<script>
document.getElementById('send-to-many').onclick = function() {
 FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'You should learn more about blabla].',
  }, Log.info.bind('send-to-many callback'));
}
</script>
```